# Find and return the partial string itself

Tags: r, string

I have a dataframe with strings on it. I want to find if a partial string is found within each element. As an output I want a dataframe (eventually the same) where I have NA for each element where the partial string was not found, and the actual partial string (only!) whenever it is found.

Moreover, I have more than one partial string... And I know that 2 of those partial strings will never be in the same element!

The closest I got to it was:

```
for(i in 1:length(partial_strings)){
  z <- apply(y,2,function(k)str_replace(k,partial_strings[i], partial_strings[i]))
}
z <- ifelse(z %in% partial_strings,z,NA)
```

But unfortunately, the str_replace instead of returning only the partial string, it is returning the original element. I can understand why, but I've tried other things which only make the output further way from what I want.

Thanks in advance

Comment: please provide a sample data set. You can do this generally with the `grepl` command. The unit-case statement is something along the lines of `df$column[!grepl('partial string', df$column)] = NA`

Comment: If I understand it correctly, you have a character vector, just like:
    `StringVector <- c("Week39","Week40","Wk41","number50","nbr51","Wk44")`

And let's say the partial string or the pattern you want to identify from the above vector is "Week" as well as "Wk";
`patterns <- c("Week","Wk")
grepl(paste(patterns, collapse="|"), StringVector)` ; Depends on what your partial strings are, you can design ifelse() within a apply function like you did above.

Answer (score 0):

`str_extract` in the `stringr` package is the way to go. It uses regex if needed, which is helpful given you have multiple partial strings to extract.

Create a string of each of your partial strings, separated by `"|"`, within brackets. For example, to extract either `"abc"` or `"def"` from a character vector called `text`:

```
str_extract(text, "(abc|def)")
```

If returns a vector of character strings of the same length as `text`, containing `"abc"` and `"def"` wherever they are matched. If one single string matches both of the partial strings, only the first is returned (eg. `str_extract("abcghdbdef", "(abc|def)")` returns only `"abc"`), although you suggest above that this isn't going to occur. Where no partial is matched, it returns `NA`.